# How to run a function upon successful execution of another function

Tags: php, laravel, twilio-api, twilio-php

I have 2 functions that uses Twilio to send media files and text messages respectively. Most times, I want to send photo then a text message. However, when I call both functions, the text message sends before the photo. How do I ensure that the photo sends first before the text.

```
//sends photo
   public static function sendMediaMessage($phone, $mediaUrl, $msg = null){
        try{

            $client = new Client(env('TWILIO_SID'), env('TWILIO_TOKEN'));
            $send = $client->messages->create(
                "whatsapp:".$phone,
                array(
                    'from' => "whatsapp:".env('TWILIO_NUMBER'), 
                    'body' => $msg,
                    'mediaUrl' => [$mediaUrl],

                )
            );

        }catch (\Exception $exception){

        }
    }

//send text messages
public static function sendWhatsAppMessage($phone, $message){

        try{

            $client = new Client(env('TWILIO_SID'), env('TWILIO_TOKEN'));
            $send = $client->messages->create(
                "whatsapp:".$phone, // Text this number
                array(
                    'from' => "whatsapp:".env('TWILIO_NUMBER'), 
                    'body' => $message
                )
            );

        }catch (\Exception $exception){

        }

    }
```

Makes call

```
myClass::sendMediaMessage();
myClass::sendWhatsAppMessage();
```

Comment: I can't be certain, however, I would imagine this will be out of your control as Twilio might used different queues for the different types of messages. As well, using this article as an example: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134247-Can-my-SMS-messages-arrive-in-order-, it may also be down to the carrier.

Answer (score 2):

Twillio [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#create-a-message-resource) suggests you can supply a callback url using the `statusCallback` field.

> If specified, we POST these message status changes to the URL: queued, failed, sent, delivered, or undelivered.

You could configure a route for it and then send the second message.

Alternatively you could look into the [message feedback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-feedback-resource) system Twillio has in place.

> To track message feedback, you must set ProvideFeedback=true when you first create the Message. This will create a Message Feedback instance with an Outcome of unconfirmed.

I'm not sure which of the above should be used, that's up to you.